# A variable issue not showing on the front end

Tags: php, variables

Here is the code I have:

in the php file:

```
if($special>0){
                            $lease_price = (($special/1000)*38);
                            } else {
                            $lease_price = (($price/1000)*38);
                            }
                            $lease_price = $this->currency->format($lease_price);
```

and in the front end tpl file:

```
                        <p>
                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
                            <b>Lease To Buy Price:</b>
                            <span><?php if($price>500){ ?>
              <?php echo $lease_price; ?>
              <?php } else { echo 'NA'; } ?></span>                     
                        </p>
```

Now I believe this works, but I think I'm entering the php code in the wrong area of the php document which is causing the variable $lease_price to not work.

Here's a link to a pastebin of my php file, where would I enter the code above? http://pastebin.com/bTPtvgUQ

Thanks for the help

Comment: How is the tpl file rendered/loaded, are you using some sort of framework

Comment: I think the variable $lease_price doesn't exist in the front end file. Did you use var_dump($lease_price) to see if this variable has the value you are waiting ?

Comment: first of all try to use inline if statemants in such cases `<?php echo $price>500?$lease_price:'NA'  ?>`. The error might be somewhere in php, did you try to dump the variable or may be rendering is incorrect?

Comment: We're using a theme on Opencart. I have not dumped the variable, I'm a newbie when it comes to php, usually doing front end html/css work. Let me try and use an inline statement then I'll try dumping the variable

Comment: inline statement will not fix the problem, it is just a better style of coding

Comment: I get this error Notice: Undefined variable: special in /var/www/framec.co.uk/catalog/controller/product/product.php on line 170Notice: Undefined variable: price in /var/www/framec.co.uk/catalog/controller/product/product.php on line 173  when trying to use an inline statement

Comment: so as WayneC said, view is not rendered correctly or the variable is not sent from controller

Comment: @LazKarimov How would I fix this? - I also got this error when var_dump was run Notice: Undefined variable: lease_price in /var/www/framec.co.uk/catalog/view/theme/lexus_superstore/template/product/product.tpl on line 160NULL