# Undefined Variable - How to Fix?

Tags: php, variables, undefined

This is the code I have:

in the php file:

```
if($special>0){
    $lease_price = (($special/1000)*38);
} else {
    $lease_price = (($price/1000)*38);
}
$lease_price = $this->currency->format($lease_price);
```

and in the front end tpl file:

```
<p>
   <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
   <b>Lease To Buy Price:</b>
   <span><?php if($price>500){ ?>
       <?php echo $lease_price; ?>
   <?php } else { echo 'NA'; } ?></span>                     
</p>
```

At the moment I'm getting this issue after var dump: `Notice: Undefined variable: lease_price in /var/www/framec.co.uk/catalog/view/theme/lexus_superstore/template/product/product.tpl on line 160NULL`

Here's a link to a pastebin of my php file http://pastebin.com/bTPtvgUQ

What do I need to add to make this work? Do I need some sort of code like this?:

```
'type' => $option['type'],
```

Here's a link to the page this is on http://www.framec.co.uk/index.php?route=product/product&path=59_78&product_id=45

Comment: possible duplicate of [A variable issue not showing on the front end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443024/a-variable-issue-not-showing-on-the-front-end)

Comment: "*Undefined Variable - How to Fix*".. Define it..? Or check if isset before trying to do something with it. Better, redesign your code structure so you never try to access a variable which could possibly be undefined in some way.

Comment: How do I define it? Where do I define it? @James

Comment: Maybe you don't pass `$lease_price` to your template?

Comment: `<?php if(isset($lease_price) { echo $lease_price; } ?>` or use a ternary operator. And/or check if it's set elsewhere.

Comment: `<?php echo (isset($lease_price)) ? $lease_price : ''; ?>` +1 for @Fred-ii-.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: @TiborB. +1 for the ternary operator ;)

Comment: How would I do this @Justinas ? <?php echo if($special>0){
                            (($special/1000)*38);
                            } else {
                            (($price/1000)*38);
                            } ?>

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to handle this.

### Initialise it:

So it's defined and PHP won't return an error when you try to use it.

```
$lease_price = '';

if($special>0){
    $lease_price = (($special/1000)*38);
} else {
    $lease_price = (($price/1000)*38);
}
$lease_price = $this->currency->format($lease_price);
```

### Don't use it if not set:

Your code which tries to access the undefined variable won't be accessed if it's not defined.

```
if ( isset($lease_price) ) {

    if($special>0){
      $lease_price = (($special/1000)*38);
    } else {
      $lease_price = (($price/1000)*38);
    }
  $lease_price = $this->currency->format($lease_price);
}
```

Comment: Hi @James I don't mind it just printing NA if the price is less than 500. I've used the code Alex suggested above but it's still printing NA. Do you know what could be the issue here? I'm really struggling getting this working and any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @BCGB Not sure to be honest. Alex's code is quite a change to your original code, and also this is now a different issue. Your original issue was to resolve an undefined var. Maybe time for a new question?

Answer (score 0):

Try merging it to one, if it won't work any other way :)

The problem will most likely be that it is not passed on properly from your PHP page to your TPL.

```
<p>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
<b>Lease To Buy Price:</b>
<span>
<?php 
if($special > 0) { 
    $lease_price = (($special/1000)*38); 
} else { 
    $lease_price = (($price/1000)*38); } 
$lease_price = $this->currency->format($lease_price);

if($price > 500) { 
echo $lease_price; 
} else { 
echo 'NA'; } ?></span>                     
</p>
```

In any normal cases you should check if

```
if(isset($lease_price)) {
    // this gets executed if $lease_price has a value
} else {
    // and this one if there is no initial value for $lease_price
}
```

You could handle this error with plenty of different approaches, but I think the key would be to ensure that your PHP code is in the right place, and referenced correctly in your template.

As there was a very similar post earlier on SO, I still think you should check the value of `$price` by adding this to your template as a temporary error checking `<?= $price ?>` since it might have already been converted to a string, and the `if($price > 500)` will never get evaluated as `'2,000.00' > 500` will not be true.

**Update**

```
$tempPrice = str_replace(',',"", $price); //gets rid of ","
$tempPrice = substr($tempPrice,1); //removes currency from the front
$tempPrice = floatval($tempPrice); //converts to double from string
```

and replace `$price` with `$tempPrice` in `if`

```
<p>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
<b>Lease To Buy Price:</b>
<span>
<?php 

$tempPrice = str_replace(',',"", $price); //gets rid of ","
$tempPrice = substr($tempPrice,1); //removes currency from the front
$tempPrice = floatval($tempPrice); //converts to double from string

if($special > 0) { 
    $lease_price = (($special/1000)*38); 
} else { 
    $lease_price = (($tempPrice/1000)*38); } 
$lease_price = $this->currency->format($lease_price);

if($tempPrice > 500) { 
echo $lease_price; 
} else { 
echo 'NA'; } ?></span>                     
</p>
```

Comment: Hi @AlexSzabó I've entered the code above in the TPL doc, the lease_price is what the piece of code is trying to work out. So basically, the lease price is the normal price /1000*38. I've added the <?= $price ?> piece of code and that prints the price no problem. But the lease price is still showing as NA. Is there something I'm missing here? Am I being a complete idiot?

Comment: @BCGB What did `<?= $price ?>` output? `2000` or `2,000.00`?

Comment: It outputted the price formatted like this: £2,000.00

Comment: @BCGB Then your `$price` variable is being treated as text, not a number therefore it cannot be compared with the value of 500. Try using what I've just updated above to convert `$price` to a number.

Comment: Ah, I see. I've implemented this, but as you can see here: http://www.framec.co.uk/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=50 the product is over £500 but is still showing NA.